# google-services.json does not exist xamarin

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm writing a cross-platform application in Xamarin. I have a problem with push notification (at the moment with google-services.json),

This is massage with error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ifEpf.png)

These are packages that needed to be installed

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AwSEH.png)

I modifyed .csproj file in TextEdit by adding the following line

```
<ItemGroup> <GoogleServicesJson Include="google-services.json" /> </ItemGroup>
```

I tried to clean/rebuild project or restart Xamarin IDE many times, but the results are not consistent.

Comment: Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Order: text, problem, code/figures, errorcode, and somewhere "I tried A, B, and C (see links).

Comment: Please make sure your `google-services.json` file build Action is `GoogleServicesJson`.